# Firefox stopped working when moving from selenium 3 beta 2 to new version

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, geckodriver

Firefox stopped working when I try to upgrade from selenium 3 beta-2 to any new version. I tried selenium 3 beta3 and 4 and selenium 3.0.1

Below is what I use:
Firefox 48.0.2 and I also tried Firefox 49.0.2
Geckodriver v0.10.0
Selenium 3.0.1 and I also tried Selenium 3 beta3 and beta 4
Windows 7 machine.
My project is using maven.

Here is the error message that I get when the test tries to launch firefox.

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.net.PortProber.waitForPortUp(IILjava/util/concurrent/TimeUnit

Everything works fine when I revert back to Selenium 3 beta 2.

Answer (score 0):

After spending hours looking for an answer. I found that this issue happens if you are using maven project and selenium 3.0.1 dependency in your pom file.

The workaround that worked for me is to add Selenium firefox dependency in addition to selenium server dependency in your pom file.

This workaround is temporary until they release selenium 3.0.2

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-firefox-driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```